# Biometric Enable and disable check in android programatically

Tags: java, android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am implementing biometric auntentication in my application. Before showing up the prompt I want to check whether it is enable or disabled usecase. For the first case, biometric success callback is fetched. I disabled the fingerprint in my mobile settings and tried to fecth value,it is returning true(0)-> BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS.

Here is my code snippet

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button authenticateButton = findViewById(R.id.button_biometric);
        authenticateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean result = hasBiometricCapability();
                Log.d("Mainactivity", String.valueOf(result));
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(result), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //showBiometricPrompt();
            }
        });


    }


    private boolean hasBiometricCapability() {
        BiometricManager biometricManager = BiometricManager.from(this);
        Log.d("Mainactivity", String.valueOf(biometricManager.canAuthenticate()));

        return biometricManager.canAuthenticate() == BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS;
    }

    private void showBiometricPrompt() {
        BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric Authentication")
                .setDescription("Please authenticate with your biometrics to continue")
                .setDeviceCredentialAllowed(false)
                .setNegativeButtonText("cancel")
                .build();

        BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(this,
                ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this),
                new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                        super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
                        super.onAuthenticationFailed();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
    }
```

In the above code snippet am getting true even i disable the fingerprint option in the device settings manually. I should get error/ false response if it is disabled. If it is deleted, I am getting as false but I have no idea how to check for disabled condition.